# Python program will not read a txt file in 16bit characters

Tags: python-3.x, file

My question is how I get python to read a file where the text is in 16bit characters. The rest of the post describes the situation.

I have a text file which is a playlist export from iTunes.
Here is a short section including the header

```
Name    Artist  Composer    Album   Grouping    Work    Movement Number Movement Count  Movement Name   Genre   Size    Time    Disc Number Disc Count  Track Number    Track Count Year    Date Modified   Date Added  Bit Rate    Sample Rate Volume Adjustment   Kind    Equalizer   Comments    Plays   Last Played Skips   Last Skipped    My Rating
Keyboard Works of the Masters   Randolph Hokanson       Pan125b                         2054816 64                      03/11/2017, 18:00   03/11/2017, 17:01   256 44100       MPEG audio file         1   03/11/2017, 17:02   4   08/03/2018, 16:07   
08 Traccia 08                                       11159905    464                     03/11/2017, 17:39   03/11/2017, 16:59   192 48000       MPEG audio file                 1   03/11/2017, 16:59   
09 Traccia 09                                       17787361    741                     03/11/2017, 17:39   03/11/2017, 16:58   192 48000       MPEG audio file                 5   08/03/2018, 10:58   
10 Traccia 10                                       10128290    421                     03/11/2017, 17:39   03/11/2017, 16:58   192 48000       MPEG audio file                 1   03/11/2017, 16:58
```

When I use this code to read it, the program hangs. (The i holds the number of lines in the file). The hex dumps which follow seem to show the export from iTunes is in 16bit characters.

The complete code for reading the text file is

```
file_name="full path to file goes here"
f = open(file_name, "r")
i=227
for x in range(0, i):
        line = f.readline()
```

When I read the code into text wrangler, selected all the text, and pasted it into a new document. The code worked fine.

A text dump of part of the original file looks like this to start with the new file following

```
00000000: FF FE 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 09 00 41 00 72 00   ..N.a.m.e...A.r.
00000010: 74 00 69 00 73 00 74 00 09 00 43 00 6F 00 6D 00   t.i.s.t...C.o.m.
00000020: 70 00 6F 00 73 00 65 00 72 00 09 00 41 00 6C 00   p.o.s.e.r...A.l.
00000030: 62 00 75 00 6D 00 09 00 47 00 72 00 6F 00 75 00   b.u.m...G.r.o.u.
00000040: 70 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 09 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00   p.i.n.g...W.o.r.
00000050: 6B 00 09 00 4D 00 6F 00 76 00 65 00 6D 00 65 00   k...M.o.v.e.m.e.
00000060: 6E 00 74 00 20 00 4E 00 75 00 6D 00 62 00 65 00   n.t. .N.u.m.b.e.
00000070: 72 00 09 00 4D 00 6F 00 76 00 65 00 6D 00 65 00   r...M.o.v.e.m.e.
00000080: 6E 00 74 00 20 00 43 00 6F 00 75 00 6E 00 74 00   n.t. .C.o.u.n.t.
00000090: 09 00 4D 00 6F 00 76 00 65 00 6D 00 65 00 6E 00   ..M.o.v.e.m.e.n.
000000A0: 74 00 20 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 09 00 47 00   t. .N.a.m.e...G.
000000B0: 65 00 6E 00 72 00 65 00 09 00 53 00 69 00 7A 00   e.n.r.e...S.i.z.
000000C0: 65 00 09 00 54 00 69 00 6D 00 65 00 09 00 44 00   e...T.i.m.e...D.
000000D0: 69 00 73 00 63 00 20 00 4E 00 75 00 6D 00 62 00   i.s.c. .N.u.m.b.
000000E0: 65 00 72 00 09 00 44 00 69 00 73 00 63 00 20 00   e.r...D.i.s.c. .
000000F0: 43 00 6F 00 75 00 6E 00 74 00 09 00 54 00 72 00   C.o.u.n.t...T.r.
```

New file

```
0000: 4E 61 6D 65 09 41 72 74 69 73 74 09 43 6F 6D 70   Name.Artist.Comp
0010: 6F 73 65 72 09 41 6C 62 75 6D 09 47 72 6F 75 70   oser.Album.Group
0020: 69 6E 67 09 57 6F 72 6B 09 4D 6F 76 65 6D 65 6E   ing.Work.Movemen
0030: 74 20 4E 75 6D 62 65 72 09 4D 6F 76 65 6D 65 6E   t Number.Movemen
0040: 74 20 43 6F 75 6E 74 09 4D 6F 76 65 6D 65 6E 74   t Count.Movement
0050: 20 4E 61 6D 65 09 47 65 6E 72 65 09 53 69 7A 65    Name.Genre.Size
```

Comment: show the rest of your file open code - not only parts

Comment: Yeah, you're probably not specifying the encoding (or specifying the wrong encoding) in the `open()`.

Comment: added the lines to show putting filename into the variable f.

Comment: @glibdud your idea was correct. I just haven't had to specify encoding before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file beginning looks like UTF-16 - see [Byte order marks - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding)

Use

```
file_name="full path to file goes here"

with io.open(file_name,'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with line
```

when opening it.

There is no need to use range() or readlines() when reading line by line. If you really need the line-numbers use:

```
    for lineNr,line in enumerate(f):
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the -le for ?

Comment: This did the job.   f = open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-16')

Comment: @nerak99  There is LowEndianess and BigEndianess - each utf16-character consists of 2 bytes, the Endianess tells it if the higher or lower byte comes first. Different OperatingSystems / encodings use them differently. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness